# How to trigger onchange only when the content changes in draft js editor?

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor, draftjs

The onchange method in draft js is executed by the Editor when edits and selection changes occur. But I want to call trigger onchange only when the user is writing or the content changes and not on focus or selection. Is there any way I can compare the previous and current editor state?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do exactly that because draft-js keep selection state of your mouse inside the editor state, `onChange` must be triggered, and you must update the editor state, but you check for the old and new editor state plain text and know for sure if some characters are added or deleted

```js
const [editorState,setEditorState]= useState(EditorState.createEmpty());

function onChange(newEditorState: EditorState) {
    
    const currentPlainText = editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText();
    const newPlainText = newEditorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText();

    setEditorState(newEditorState);


    if (currentPlainText.trim() !== newPlainText.trim()) {

        /**
         * do what you want knowing that you have different content in the editor
         */
    }

}
```

Comment: this will work only if the content itself changes, but not if the inline style changes

Answer (score 2):

I use `undoStack.size` property to detect the content change. It works great.

https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor-state/#undostack

```
onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
  const changed = !!editorState.getUndoStack().size
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats works but be careful  if you use it directly like `changed && setState(editorState)` can cause some problems when you put cursor in different place and try to change text in editor